# Does the Javascript standard library contain a http object?

Tags: javascript, http, https, airtable

I am looking to do some custom scripting in Airtable, which says that "you can use anything from the JavaScript standard library, except for DOM APIs that interact with HTML on the page".

I want the script to interact with the gsuite API, but can't seem to find any reference in the javascript standard library documentation on making http/s calls.

I'm a newbie so may be completely missing something, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest might be what you are searching for.
This MDN link should help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: It may not end up solving the problem (need to look more into authentication etc) but this is absolutely put me on the right path. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is reading this Stack question in 2022, Fetch is **newer** than XMLHttpRequest and is also available to use for your custom scripts in AirTable: https://www.airtable.com/developers/scripting/api/fetch

MDN Link for Fetch:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API